# Error when trying to delete items from Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

When I want close the application, I get the following error:

```
Exception _tkinter.TclError: 'invalid command name ".47045488"' in <bound method
RootJoint.__del__ of <skeleton.RootJoint object at 0x0000000002CDDBA8>> ignored
```

And here is the relevant part from `RootJoint`:

```
def __init__(self, canvas):
    self.parent = None
    self.angle = 0.0
    self.distance = 0.0

    topleft = 0 - Joint.SQUARE_HALF_SIDE, 0 + Joint.SQUARE_HALF_SIDE
    bottomright = 0 + Joint.SQUARE_HALF_SIDE, 0 - Joint.SQUARE_HALF_SIDE

    self._joint = canvas.create_rectangle(*(topleft + bottomright))
    canvas.itemconfig(self._joint, fill=RootJoint.COLOR_NORMAL)

    self.canvas = canvas

def __del__(self):
    self.canvas.delete(self._joint)
```

And this is where the canvas and root joint are created:

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('640x480')

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
    canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    rootjoint = skeleton.RootJoint(canvas)

    root.mainloop()
```

Why is this error appearing and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that

**del**

is called when the last reference to the canves is lost and the object is deleted.

what you want is

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.bind("<Destroy>", self.onDestroy)
def onDestroy(self, event):
    self.canvas.delete(self._joint)
```

first the canvas and all elements will be destroyed and destructed and then deleted

Comment: Is `'<Destroy>'` the event emitted when the entire canvas is destroyed or when the current object is destroyed? I will need to be able to remove joints from the screen during the execution, so this is important.

Comment: And how is the last reference to the canvas lost? The root joint has its own reference to the canvas.

Comment: you alway can remove those items but in __del__ it is too late to do so: last chance is onDestroy

Comment: add a print in __del__ and a print in main() after root.mainloop()
 to see what is executed when. i guess __del__ is called after main() left.

Comment: I tried it, this doesn't work either. The callbacks to `'<Destroy>'` still get called right *after* the destruction, not before? Is there some event like `'<BeforeDestroy>'`?